# Does Cross-account resource accessing policy rule work (non-assume-role)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I have a Lambda function in AWS account "xxxxxxxxxx", and its execution role's permission is as follows:

```
{
            "Action": [
                "dynamodb:PutItem",
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:yyyyyyyyyy:table/testingtable"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
}
```

Basically it's allowing the Lambda function to put item in account "yyyyyyyyyy" which is another account.

However, when I call PutItemRequest on table `testingtable` in my lambda function, it seemed to be accessing table of the same account as the role "xxxxxxxxxx", because I got error back saying

```
role not authorized to perform: dynamodb:PutItem on resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-west-2:xxxxxxxxxxx:table/testingtable
```

How do I explicitly tell the Dynamodb client to access the table(or any other resources) in a different account "yyyyyyyyyy"? is it doable? (I am aware that I can let the Lambda role assume a role in account yyyyyyyyy but I didn't want do that.)

Comment: DynamoDb does not have resouce based policies. Can you clarify what do you do? Your lambda must assume-role in other account to access the db in that account.

Comment: @Marcin I want Lambda function in account A to have write/read access to DDB in account B without assuming a role of account A. Is it achievable? what about Lambda function in account A to have write/read access to S3 bucket in account B without assuming role?

Comment: I don't think its possible. DynamoDB, unlike S3, doesn't have resource-based policies. Thus the only for your function to access DDB in Acc B, is to have some IAM role in Acc B which can be assumed by the function with the permissions to the db. Obviously, you could use IAM user in Acc B if you don't want to assume role, but the use of the IAM roles is a good practice for cross-account access.

Comment: can you please advise or provide some example of how resource-based policy for S3 could work?

Comment: I guess it's https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/

Comment: Yes, but this is for S3. DynamoDb does not have resource-based policies. Thus, you can't use this approach.

Comment: Let me restate your question: "I want to be able to be able to access resources in account B from account A, _without getting permission from account B._" Thankfully, it doesn't work that way. You'll have to assume a role.